# How to get the Object Value and add to Arraylist in Java without for loop

Tags: java, android

Getting the Object value and add to Arraylist and then I have to check arraylist contains string or not.

Below is the POJO Class, finally this will get as Object

```
public class OrderTypeFeature{

    public OrderTypeFeature(ODataEntity entity){
        create(entity);
    }

    private String OrderType;
    private String Feature;

    public String getOrderType() {
        return OrderType;
    }

    public void setOrderType(String orderType) {
        OrderType = orderType;
    }

    public String getFeature() {
        return Feature;
    }

    public void setFeature(String feature) {
        Feature = feature;
    }

    public static ArrayList<OrderTypeFeature> getOrderTypeFeatures(String orderType){

        ArrayList<OrderTypeFeature> orderTypeFeatures = new ArrayList<>();
        ResponseObject result = new ResponseObject(ConfigManager.Status.Error);

        try {

            String resourcePath = Collections.LT_ORDERTYPEFEATURESET+"?$filter=(OrderType eq '"+ orderType +"')";

            result = DataHelper.getInstance().getEntities(resourcePath, StoreSettings.Stores.MdLV);

            if(!result.isError()){
                List<ODataEntity> entities = (List<ODataEntity>) result.Content();
                for (ODataEntity entity : entities){
                    orderTypeFeatures.add(new OrderTypeFeature(entity));
                }
            }

        }catch (Exception e){

            result.setMessage(e.getMessage());
            DliteLogger.WriteLog(OrderTypeFeature.class, AppSettings.LogLevel.Error, e.getMessage());

        }
            return orderTypeFeatures;
        }

}
```

Below are the links which I referred
[How to retrieve objects values stored in a Java ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9238241/how-to-retrieve-objects-values-stored-in-a-java-arraylist)
but didn't worked out

I have to get the Object Value to ArrayList and then I have to compare the Object value with the String without using For loop.
Please help me guys.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether an ArrayList (or in fact any class implementing the List interface) contains an element by calling

```
List.contains(Object)
```

Have a look at the Java [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains-java.lang.Object-) for more information.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your response, I have added like this.Can you please check       ----         ArrayList<OrderTypeFeature> ort = new ArrayList<>();
        OrderTypeFeature a = new OrderTypeFeature();
        ort.add(a);

Comment: You're welcome. Your code to add the element looks good. Please mark the answer as accepted if it helped you.

Comment: Hauke, Thanks for your response, I am getting the values as null.Can you please help me on this please ?

Comment: Your code is alright, your Exception may be thrown elsewhere.

Comment: ArrayList<String> ort = new ArrayList<>();
        OrderTypeFeature a = new OrderTypeFeature();
        ort.add(a.getFeature())      -----this code giving me null

Comment: As I said, the code snipped you provided is ok. The issue may be in the implementation of OrderTypeFeature. Analyze your stack trace...

Comment: How to add value of Object(OrderTypeFeature) to arraylist by using this method "getOrderTypeFeatures" in OrderTypeFeature,?  "getOrderTypeFeatures" can be seen in the above code.Please help me on this.